# How to mute left/right channel and play PCM data in another channel using android AudioTrack

Tags: android, audio, audiotrack

I need to generate a tone with desired frequency and it should play in channel(left/right) and mute another channel. ie zero volume in another channel and full volume in another channel. I've tried using `audioTrack.setStereoVolume(0,1)` and `audioTrack.setStereoVolume(1,0)`, but still i can hear tone with less volume in another channel.